# Salesforce Refresh Error Entity of type 'WorkflowFieldUpdate' Not found

Tags: deployment, salesforce, force-ide

> Refresh error: Entity of type 'WorkflowFieldUpdate' named 'Case.ISHERE' not found    Project/src    package.xml    line 1    1248190153153    205

any ideas what this means?

It's stopping us from deploying, as workflows don't appear on the deployment candidate list in Eclipse.

The fieldUpdates, definitely do exist in the Sanbox, when it says "not found" does in mean on the server or in the  `src\workflows\Case.workflow` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your package.xml file references a workflow field update on Case called "ISHERE", but there is no corresponding file on your local filesystem.  You should either remove the reference in package.xml if you don't care about that being deployed or you should do a refresh from server to get the latest metadata (watch out for any local changes you've made!).